# Foundation – Deep linking to accordion tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zurb-foundation

Am I able to deep link to a tab inside Accordion?

For example, let's say I am clicking a link such as http://domain.com/page#tab-23 from an external source – how can I make tab 23 active/opened when the page is loaded?

There is a deep_linking option for Tabs, but not for Accordion.

Thanks.

Comment: You give that specific div of the accordion an id (for example let's call it 'div23'), you will access it via http://domain.com/page#div23

Comment: Thanks. They already have IDs which is working for scrolling to that point on the page, but I want the specific tab in the Accordion to be opened as well on load. Possible?

Answer (score 3):

It's not the most elegant but you could look for a hash in the URL and trigger a click on the corresponding accordion element.

**JS**

```
if(window.location.hash) {
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  $('.accordion a[href="' + hash + '"]').trigger('click');
}
```

Here's a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/ascwwyr7/).